# gesture detector in child is blocking transform in pageview

Tags: flutter, dart

The gesturedetector is placed in child widget

```
behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
            onHorizontalDragDown: (_) {
              widget.controller.pause();
            },
            onHorizontalDragCancel: () {
              widget.controller.play();
            },
```

Parent is a PageView with itemBuilder of many similar child,both have pageController

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        double value;
        if (_pageController.position.haveDimensions == false) {
          value = index.toDouble();
        } else {
          value = _pageController.page;
        }
        return _SwipeWidget(
          index: index,
          pageNotifier: value,
          child: children[index],
        );
      },
```

calling Gesturedetector in child makes the swipe animation in pageView with transform not work

Comment: try adding to pageView physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics()

Comment: i need to swipe the pages